# Upgrade / Retrofit old security system

Tags: security

I purchased a building that has an old ADT hard wired alarm system.  I have a full set of cameras installed that allows me to monitor the building, so I would like to upgrade the alarm to one of the newer systems that simply makes noise and notifies your phone if triggered instead of having it monitored.  All the door sensors and motion detectors from the old system work great and I would like to utilize them.  Is it possible to purchase and install a kit that will do this allowing me to use the existing sensors and if so, where do I look/what am I looking for?

Comment: This question is both very broad and worded like a [shopping question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which are not a good fit for the site.  I have looked for this in the past, and didn't find anything I liked, but hopefully there is something now.

Comment: An old system probably uses a phone line to call the monitoring company if there is an alarm. If you can find a user's manual you might be able to change the phone number to your cell phone. The audio will be incomprehensible computer code garbage, but you will know what it means.

Comment: Thanks to all!  I think you have me heading in the right direction now.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensors are generic and in good working order, and you just want local alarms (sirens, strobes, etc.) you can install any basic alarm panel without monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices, you should look for one with the features you want and the ecosystem (Amazon, Google/Nest, Apple) that you like.

These are called "retrofit smart security" kits and the most well-known is Konnected, although Ring and others have their own branded versions.

Installation looks pretty straightforward but may take some DIY know-how on your part depending on how mature and consumer-friendly your kit is.

Comment: That Konnected model looks interesting.  Seems like a low-volume kickstarter type deal so I'm not sure how "well known" it is, but looks great for a smart home sucker like me.